# about a message appeared on my StackExchange page

Tags: discussion

What does it mean: "TeX might not render (GoDaddy was hacked) "? I will attach a picture [image]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[GoDaddy.com was hacked](http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/10/godaddy-outage-takes-down-millions-of-sites/) and it was affecting some parts of the DNS system. The domain `cdn.mathjax.org` was failing to resolve. This caused a long lag in loading pages that were MathJax enabled and finally prevented the MathJax from rendering.

I should add that only a fraction of the users were affected; only those in specific areas. No stackexchange accounts were compromised by this action.